# Understanding Proof of proposition 2B.1. in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is part (a) of the the proposition.

(a) For an embedding $h:D^k \rightarrow S^n$, $\tilde{H}_i(S^n-h(D^k))=0$  $\forall i$.

Given $A=S^n-h(I^{k-1}\times[0,1/2])$ and $B=S^n-h(I^{k-1}\times[1/2,1])$, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence associated to these gives us an isomorphism $\Psi:\tilde{H}_i(S^n-h(I^k)) \to \tilde{H}_i(A) \oplus \tilde{H}_i(B)$.

I do not understand how, if $\alpha$ is not a boundary in $S^n-h(I^k)$,  he concludes $\alpha$ is not boundary in at least one of $A$ and $B$, by knowing $\phi$ is an isomorphisms and its components modulo signs are induced by natural inclusions.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flpSP.png) is a picture of the proof.

I know it might be obvious for some of you but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the step in the proof where you are confused, Hatcher has shown using Mayer-Vietoris that the map $\Phi: \tilde{H}_n(A \cap B) \to \tilde{H}_n(A) \oplus \tilde{H}_n(B)$ given by $[\alpha] \mapsto ([i_A\alpha],-[i_B\alpha])$ is an isomorphism where $i_A, i_B$ are the respective inclusions.

If $\alpha$ is a boundary in both $A$ and $B$, then there is a chain $\beta \in C_{n+1}A$ so $i_A\alpha = \partial \beta$, hence $[i_A \alpha] = [\partial \beta] = [0]$ in $\tilde{H}_n(A)$. An identical argument shows $[i_B \alpha] = 0 \in H_n(B)$. We conclude that $\Phi[\alpha] = (0,0)$ so as $\Phi$ is an isomorphism, $[\alpha] = 0$ in $\tilde H_n(A\cap B)$. This shows that for any $[\alpha] \neq 0$ in $\tilde H_n(A \cap B)$, either $[i_A \alpha]$ or $[i_B\alpha]$ is not $0$ in their respective homology groups (i.e. not a boundary).